# $_POST method showing undefine variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, localhost

How to solve this i don't add data using by $_Post Method, but without $_POST method showing undefine variable?

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['age'])){

        //Getting values
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];

        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";

        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('connect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Employee Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Employee';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin not only, even xss ones

Comment: use `empty()` instead of `isset()` to determine if the value of the post variables are empty.

Comment: @YehiaAwad — XSS problems occur when outputting text into HTML (or JS and sometimes CSS). That isn't happening here. (Some other bit of PHP that isn't in the question might pull data out of a database and introduce an XSS problem, but it isn't here).

Comment: @Quentin what if I insert Data as <script> .... </script> and he just output it somewhere on his site

Comment: @YehiaAwad — Exactly. "What if". We can't see the output code.

Comment: @Quentin I got what you meant !

Comment: Specific problem i don't insert data, actually isset($_Post[]) method don't work properly, what i do??

Comment: What variables are showing undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your variables to something if $_POST is not set.

So code would look something like this:

```
$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] ? "";
$lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : "";
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : "";
//if isset $_POST['age'] then assign it to $_POST['age'] else assign it to ""  



if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['age'])){

        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";

        //Importing our db connection script
        require_once('connect.php');

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Employee Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Employee';
        }

        //Closing the database 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

**Bonus:**

You code can be easily injected. Use prepared statements to avoid this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES (?,?,?)"; // question marks are placeholders to bind values to
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); // prepare query
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $age); // bind values to your query
if($stmt->execute()){ // if success
    echo 'Employee Added Successfully';
}else{
    echo 'Could Not Add Employee';
}
```

You can learn more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['age'])),    this line specific problem, without this line code is work, but showing undefined variable,

Comment: @AzharulIslam Can you add some more of your code. Code related to the variables $firstname, $lastname and $age

Comment: @AzharulIslam did you try my code? if not give it a try. I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: <?php
require_once('db_config.php');


$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

?>, this is connect.php,

Comment: yeh, but same answer

Comment: @AzharulIslam What is the full error you are getting?

Comment: can u help me about json data parsing in php & mysql?? any link ?? @user3284463

Comment: there is no error but dont showing successfully added,

Comment: @AzharulIslam take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @AzharulIslam add a picture of the error you are getting to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this one:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";
```

To this one:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES ('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','."$age."')";
```

Comment: @C.Liddell Yes you are right. Try using empty() instead of isset().

Comment: @Azharul Islam Maybe it is $_GET not $_POST ? :D (sorry to post here, I cannot post comment to your question)

Where did the variables came from? Can you post more code?